# Rewrite/hiding some URL in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to get right syntax for .htaccess without any result...

I've a URL structured as domain.com/app/public/pageName .

It's working fine but I would "hide" the 'app/public/' part in browsers, basically doing something like:

```
[real URL] domain.com/app/public/pageName -> domain.com/pageName [what users type and see in browsers]
```

I think in that way it should be more readable and seo-friendly.

As I understood from docs (and maybe it's wrong because it's not working...) I should tell to Apache to map/redirect all URL like domain.com/pageName to domain.com/app/public/pageName , but only internally, in order to show the minimal URL in users' browsers.

Right now I have something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /app/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://localhost/app/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

(I'm using full URL with https://... in order to get something that will be quick and easy to adapt when I upload all to my hosting, is it right?).

Problem is that RewriteRule actually change the URL, because it perform a redirect and URL rewrite it's not handle internally.

So, first of all: is it possible what I'm trying to do? If so, how can I handle the URL rewrite only internally?

Everything should be uploaded to a shared hosting, so I don't have other than .htaccess.
Anyway, I can consider to upgrade to a vps if there are not other possibilities...

Thanks!

==============

**EDIT** (should be more clear now)

tl;dr version:

I'm looking for a method that let users to type domain.com/pageName (and they will see that address in their browsers) and rewrite internally that URL in order to point to domain.com/app/public/pageName.

==============

**More**: after /app/public/ there can be an arbitrary number of elements, separated by / . All of these elements are appended at the end of the URL after index.php. At the end URL looks like:

```
  domain/app/public/index.php?url=lot/of/elements/here
```

This is already working with the RewriteRule posted above, I would keep that too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference, I found a solution, maybe will be usefull for someone.

Basically I moved .htaccess to the root server (instead of /app/public directory) and changed the RewriteRule as follow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app/public/

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT]
```

Now it's working (at least on localhost).

What do you think? Are there any side effects with this config?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me, Hope it will work for you as well.

[Check .htaccess here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/public
RewriteRule ^app/public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hello, Your rule did not handle the internal rewrite which the op wants.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar Corrected it now it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But it's not what I was looking for. Maybe I didn't explain correctly: you are doing the exact opposite! Users type domain/app/public/page and internally Apache redirects to domain/page. I'm trying the reverse: users type domain/page and Apache handles that internally as domain/app/public/page. I updated question to clarify that.